# Is/Was/Will it be alright?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, steganography

In other news I'm drawing again. No, you can't have transcriptions. [I didn't redo my big drawing puzzle yet](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38088641#38088641) so the doodles are what I've been doing.

(I'm A-OK sorry if this alarmed anyone) :)

---

[image: Indeed they are]

---

[image: for now]

---

[image: do not run]

---

[image: forever]

---

[image: ----. ..--- -. . .-. ---.. ..-]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> [image]

If you click "edit"

> you will see that every image description is a "response" to the image but the last one

which is

> ----. ..--- -. . .-. ---.. ..-

Decoding that gives

> 92NER8U

which is

> an imgur link. https://i.imgur.com/92nEr8U.png

Comment: When I click the link in your final spoiler, I get a `404 not found`.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain it's working for me. can you see the image in the first spoiler? it's from the same link

Comment: It's working now.  Maybe Imgur was temporarily down, or I had some connection issues?